# An object near the speed of light can become a black hole at high speeds?

Tags: special-relativity, black-holes, relativity, mass-energy

If we use the Lorentz equation for the length contraction, and the Schwarzschild equation for the lightlike sphere, we can calculate the velocity for the object to form a black hole:

$ \Delta x^{'}=\Delta x\,\sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}\,\, $ --> Lorentz formula

$ r_{\text{s}}=\dfrac{2Gm}{c^2}\,\, $ --> Schwarzchild formula

$ 2r_{\text{s}}=\Delta x^{'}\,\, $ --> to a sphere

$ 2\left(\dfrac{2Gm}{c^2}\right)=\Delta x\,\sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}} $

$ v=c\,\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{4Gm}{\Delta xc^2}\right)^2} $

Is this correct? Is this the speed that the object, in the spherical case, would have to attain to become a black hole?

Sorry for my English and little knowledge of physics, I am a freshman student in a university in Brazil.

Comment: So plug in some numbers. If you had something the mass of the Earth (5.972 × 10^24 kg) what speed would you need to get for it to turn into a black hole? Can this speed exist?

Comment: Would be a velocity really very close to the speed of light, in the case of Earth, but possible in principle.

Comment: Please don't post cell-phone pictures of equations. Mark up your questions using mathjax instead. Posting pictures doesn't work with search engines and doesn't work for blind people.

Comment: Your object's already traveling very close to $c$ in *some* reference frame. So why isn't it a black hole?